# Microsoft account setup issue

Tags: windows, windows-installation

I just purchased a new lap top (Windows 8) to hedge on the upcoming demise of the old laptop (Vista). When I tried to set up the new computer it said I needed to set up a Microsoft account for that computer. (The old laptop is still working ok via the wireless router in the house). The new computer will not set up because the prompts say I already have a Microsoft account under that email address (I was doing the new setup using the email address on the old computer.)

Do I need to use a second email address to set up the Microsoft account on the new computer?